# Cannot populate an array by reading 500,000 entries from a file for memory reasons

Tags: php, arrays, readfile, chunks

I am parsing about 500.000 entries into an array `$properties`:

```
$properties = array();
$handle = fopen($file_path, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($str = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if (strlen($str) && $str[0] == '#') {
            $pdate = substr($str, 1);
            $date = rtrim($pdate);
            $formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('* M d H:i:s T Y', $date);
        }
        $str = rtrim ($str, "\n");
        $exp = explode ('=', $str);
        if (count($exp) == 2){
            $exp2 = explode('.', $exp[0]);  
            if (count($exp2) == 2) {
                if ($exp2[1] == "dateTime") {
                    $s = str_replace("\\", "", $exp[1]);
                    $d = strtotime($s);
                    $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d);
                    $properties[$exp2[0]][$exp2[1]] = $dateTime;
                } else {
                    $properties[$exp2[0]][$exp2[1]] = $exp[1];
                }
            } else {
                $properties[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
            }
        } 
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

This is working well so far, but I need to split the array into chunks, because otherwise the array is too big to work with.

```
$properties_chunk = array_chunk($properties, 10000, true);
```

But now I have the problem that the `$properties_chunk` array is not created. The system crashes. This is too much. But what can I do now?

The array should look like this in the end:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(10000) {
    ["12345"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(46) "monkey.jpg"
      ["path"]=>
      string(149) "Volumes/animals/monkey.jpg"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "2650752"
    }
    ["678790"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(45) "elephant.jpg"
      ["path"]=>
      string(171) "Volumes/animals/elephant.jpg"
      ["size"]=>
      string(7) "2306688"
    }

... and so on.
```

Comment: maybe instead of array chunk, just do a for loop from 0 - 10000. maybe no crash?

Comment: Can you just process each chunk of 10000 as you read it out of the file? Keep count, process the batch, then empty it before continuing. Or do you need them all in memory at once (to sort, etc)?

Comment: @iainn I would need the chunk at once to make a comparison with other array

Comment: increase memory limit / timeout time

Comment: @Andrew Already done this

Comment: @Andrew loop from 0-10000 But how can I do this, because I need the set together as one array "dateTime, fileName, path, size"

Comment: So, just to be clear. The full array works but when you try to chunk it it crashes? How about array_splice(), that will not create new items just move them from one array to the other, therefore the memory used should be the same(-ish). Array_chunk  will keep the original array and create a new copy with subarrays, array_splice cuts out one part to the returned array.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, exactly. Full array works. Will array_spice create the same result then array_chunk?

Comment: No not really. Let me make a demo, just a sec. See here what it does: https://3v4l.org/4YuSY see how the total number of items stay the same in the project. Array_chunk will make a copy of the input array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use array_splice the items will be moved from the input array to the resulting array.

This should mean the memory use should stay the same-ish.

This will do the same as array_chunk but hopefully be less memory hungry.

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$n = 10000;
$count = (count($arr)/$n)-1; // do not splice the last items in loop
For($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $res[] = array_splice($arr, 0,$n);
}
$res[] = array_splice($arr, 0,count($arr)); 
// here we splice the last items from arr to $res. 
// Notice how we splice count($arr) instead of $n. 
// If count($arr) == $n we could have done it in the loop. 
// But if we assume they are not, array_splice in the loop will create empty items. This line will not.

Var_dump($res, $arr); // $res has all values, $arr is empty
```

https://3v4l.org/XDpdI

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171323/discussion-on-answer-by-andreas-how-can-i-split-a-huge-array-into-chunks).

Comment: @Andreas is the `array_splice()` call after the loop necessary?  Can't you just push all of the left overs?  Did I miss something?